# Steam doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: package-management, software-installation, steam

I think I've made a mistake and now Ubuntu won't install Steam.
I've tried a number of things, uninstalling and reinstalling and it won't open it just opens the icon and it flashes for a short period of time.Any suggestions?

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Try running `steam` in the terminal and edit your question to include any error messages you see.

Comment: What's the command for running steam in the terminal?

Comment: `steam`, as I have written already.

Comment: Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Try installing Steam with the Arch package [`steam-native-runtime`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=steam-native-runtime). It configures needed libraries that are forgotten by the official [`steam_latest.deb`](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb) archive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update video driver to the latest proprietary driver available. You can do this by launching "Additional Drivers" in Unity Dash. Then select the AMD/ATI, or NVIDIA video driver.
2. Run the command below to make sure python-apt is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-apt
   ```
3. Download the official Steam '.deb' archive - [steam_latest.deb](http://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb)
4. Open a terminal window, & change directory to where you downloaded 'steam_latest.deb'. If you downloaded to '~/Downloads' then you'd enter this cmd:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
5. Now install 'steam_latest.deb' using gDebi tool, or install using 'dpkg'. You'd use this command if you wanted to install with dpkg:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
   ```
6. Launch Steam with the launcher in Unity Dash, or enter `steam` to launch w/ terminal.
7. Accept the ToS / ToC / EULA when asked. This might not be necessary if you previously accepted them.